# I can't upload multiple images to Amazon S3 using Sails.js

Tags: javascript, amazon-s3, sails.js

I'm trying to upload multiple images to Amazon S3 and using Sails.js framework.This is my code:

Fotos.ejs (Is the view for uploading photos):

```
 <form enctype="multipart/form-data" id="frmFotos">
   <input id="fotos" name="fotos" type="file">
    <button type="submit" id="btnUpload">Upload</button>
 </form>
```

Fotos.js (Ajax call for upload)

```
$('#btnUpload').on('click',function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var formData=new FormData();
    formData.append("fotos",$("#fotos")[0].files);
   $.ajax({
        url:"/upload",
        data: formData,
        processData: false,
        contentType: false,
        type: 'POST',
        success: function(data){
           console.log(data);
        }
    });
})
```

FotoController.js (Controller in Sails.js where I'm using skipper-s3 to upload files)

```
module.exports = {
  upload:function(req,res){

    var aws={
        adapter:require("skipper-s3"),
        bucket:"mybucket",
        key:"mykey",
        secret:"mysecret"
    };

    req.file("fotos").upload({aws},function whenDone(error,fotos){
        if(error)
        {
            console.log(error);
        } else{
            fotos.forEach(function(foto){
                console.log(foto);
            });
        }           
    });
  }
}
```

I think that there is an additional task because I can't see my images in the bucket in S3. I test the code with a single image and this works fine.

Answer (score 0):

You have to specify the region in which your bucket belongs. For instance:

```
var aws = {
    ... 
    region: 'us-west-2'
    ...  
}
```

Your region may be located elsewhere than US West 2. In which case, either create a new bucket in US West 2, or find your region's code (e.g.: us-west-1, us-east-1).